# Beowulf cluster hard disk problem

Tags: 14.04, permissions, mpi, beowulf

I built a Beowulf cluster using the message passing interface (MPI).

When I send a message that contains the path for a specific file in the slave node, the slave can't access its local hard disk to open the file (the error is permission denied).

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?